# onload, hide text inside textarea and onclick copy to clipboard and hide the text inside textarea after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is that possible?

When I use `onload()` function on class `hide` which is the text area, it will hide the text inside text area but when I click , it should reveal text area and copy to clipboard should be called and I have exactly 5 seconds to copy the text and then after that it should hide the text area...

Comment: You can't copy to clipboard using JavaScript (except maybe in IE).

Comment: @MrUpsidown --- using Jquery and it's working on all browser                                                                Code:                                                                 <script> function(){ var select_all = function(control){ var copy = $(control).val(); window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", copy); } $(".hide").click(function(){ select_all(this); }) </script>

Comment: Yes, so you can't copy to clipboard. Hitting Ctrl+C on your keyboard is not a javascript function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand it correctly, this is what you are looking for?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cVNnJ/

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');

for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var ta = c[i];
    ta.setAttribute('tag', ta.value);
    ta.value = '';
    ta.onclick = function() {
        this.value = this.getAttribute('tag');
        setTimeout(function() { this.value = ''; }.bind(this), 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, will you please explain as I am new to Jquery, because I will be integrating this with below function

Comment: <script>
   function(){
   var select_all = function(control){
   var copy = $(control).val();
   window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", copy);
  }
  $(".hide").click(function(){
   select_all(this);
   })
 

  </script>